# How/where to obtain a .p12 key file from the Google Developers Console?

Tags: google-workspace, google-api

I am using a custom component with Talend Open Studio that allows me to connect to Google Analytics

Part of the setup requires specifying the location of a .p12 key file

I have created a Project in the Google Developers Console, but so far not able to find any mention of downloading a key file

Where can I find/create this?

Answer (score 11):

With the new [Google Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com) the procedure to obtain the P12 key has changed:

- Open the project, go to `APIs & auth` > `Credentials`
- Click on `Create new Client ID`, and select `Service account` and `P12 key`. Then click on `Create Client ID` to download it.

Answer (score 4):

Update: 08. September 2015

- Go to [Google Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
- on the **left** press **APIs & auth**
- press **Credentials**
- click the blue button **Create credentials**
- choose **Service account**
- choose **P12**

Answer (score 2):

Inside [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console):

- Open the project, go to `APIs & auth` > `Registered apps` on the left.
- Click on `Register App`, enter name and choose platform (for e.g. `Web Application`).
- On the next page, open `Certificate` and click on `Generate Certificate` and download the `.p12` private key.

Don't forget to note the email address and password that appear when downloading the key.

To access google analytics with this key, you also need to give permission to the above email address in your analytics account.

- In Google Analytics, open the site's reporting section and click on `Admin` link on top-right.
- Under `User Management`, add `Read & Analyze` permissions for the email address you noted previously.